# Preserve list names using parallel versions of lapply function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, sapply

When I want to do some operation over the lists, and get the list with the same names as a result I use sapply function:

```
newList <- sapply(oldList, someFunction, simplify = FALSE,USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

Is it possible (and how) to do the same using parallel versions of function from apply family, eg mclapply from parallel package?

Comment: According to `?mclapply`, you can.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik, How?

Comment: See the help file. The `...` argument says you can use arguments from `sapply`.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik, ok. I found out that it works with mcmapply function, only when function is the first argument and 'SIMPLIFY' is writen in capital letters. Thanks! Could you post your answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?mclapply` help page says that this is possible (argument `SIMPLIFY`), although only for `mcmapply`. As you've already figured it out, `(mc)mapply` with only one object passed is a special case and is equivalent to `(mc)lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

There is parSapply function in parallel package - https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/clusterApply.html

```
library("parallel")
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))
newList <- parSapply(cl, oldList, someFunction, simplify = FALSE,USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```